# Squarespace system collections?

Tags: squarespace

I would like to recreate the "events" system collection, because I'd like to tweak this collection (e.g. add an squarespace block for intro text on top of the page). Does any of you have the files events.item & events.list available? I don't want to recreate these files myself. To generalise the question: is there a place where we can find the underlying files of the squarespace system collections (blog, events, gallery, index...)?

Answer (score 0):

You are able to access some of the "underlying files" of Squarespace system collections by [enabling developer mode](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206545717-Squarespace-Developer-Platform-FAQ).

> Here's how to enable Developer Mode from an existing Squarespace site.
>   (You can also start from a blank Base Template or create a trial site.
>   For details, visit Get Started - Developers.) In the Home Menu , click
>   Settings, click Advanced, and then click Developer Mode.

Once enabled, you can use Git or SFTP to access the system files. Collections such as blogs, events and index, if available for your template, will be in the "collections" folder.

Keep in mind that not all Squarespace system collections are available for every template. The [Marquee template](https://marquee-demo.squarespace.com/) is the only template I know of that provides access to its events-related collection files. There may be others. If you want to use these files as a start, you'll have to start a new website based on Marquee, enable dev. mode, grab the files, then you can delete the Marquee-based site.

Otherwise, if your template does not provide them, you'll have to write the collection files yourself.

Comment: Hi Brandon, thank you for your elaborate answer. Indeed, I have SFTP'ed into the Marquee template and downloaded the events.list & events.item file. 

Also, Jason Barone has made these available on GitHub. Both files can be found in the folder https://github.com/Squarefront/squarespace-marquee-template/blob/master/collections/

However, these files do not correspond with my Om template (Montauk based) at all: incorrect CSS classes. So I fear the only option will be to recreate the template files. Goddamn, amazing that SS or anybody did not yet publish these online!

Comment: @BarrieO: One not-so-brilliant-but-nonetheless-helpful method would be to copy the rendered source (view source) from the events page on your site, then insert JSON-T wherever hard values are located. Especially using the Marquee files as a reference, it may not be too difficult (though time consuming) to rebuild it.

Comment: Okay, hmm... I am a bit reluctant as I will run over budget for my client, but however, it can be useful for future websites as wel. In any case, thanks for the help Brandon!